# Sending an ArrayList<float[]> between activities (android)

Tags: java, android

What is the easiest way to send an `ArrayList<float[]>` between activities?

Is it possible to send using `SharedPreferences` or `putExtra`?

I've only seen examples of sending `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Int>`, and those options are built in through .`putStringArrayList` etc.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to add it as an extra to the Intent's Bundle. This is because Intent extras were created specifically to pass arguments between Activities.

*Put Extra*

```
ArrayList<float[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("arg_key", list);
```

*Get Extra*

```
ArrayList<float[]> list = ( ArrayList<float[]>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arg_key");
```

That said, if the data is to be persisted in a Database anyways, you would simply retrieve it from the database. I would not use `SharedPreferences` for this as it is intended for storing flags, tokens, app settings, etc.

**UPDATE**

If you want to pass an argument that is not supported by an Intent's extras and is not natively `Serializable`, have a look at `Parcelable`. You can implement `Parcelable` in any of your POJOs to allow them to be added to a `Bundle`. Parcelable is also faster than Serializable.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, this explains how to send a float array, but not an ArrayList of float arrays?

Comment: I updated my answer already. Using serializable should work since `ArrayList`, and `float[]` are both `Serializable`.